# Understand the built-in function unlist

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would appreciate help with how the function `unlist()` works in R, since I encounter some problems when I try to convert a list to a vector with this. My problem:

When I used this on my list `lst` with the original output `## [1,] -0.4111434 -0.1284589 -0.1824016 0.4634135 1.25859` it seems to be created into a column vector rather than a row vector. I discovered this when I was trying to calculate the equation `mean%*%t(unlist(lst))` (mean is a row-matrix with expected returns `0.001083249  0.001846313  0.002450989  0.004948962  0.005279165`) and it gave me a 5x5 matrix instead of a number.

I have used the same equation `mean%*%t(vec)` for other vectors, including for the vector `## [1,] 0.06332585 0.07328322 0.08528878 0.2380229 0.5400793` and it gave me a numerical value and not a matrix.

Hence I wonder how `unlist()` works in R, and why I get a matrix instead of a numerical value. Is it because it creates a column vector? If yes, can I turn it into a row vector instead?

Comment: `unlist` returns a vector and by default it does `recursive = TRUE` as well

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your answer, but even if I choose `recursive = FALSE` it gives me a 5x5-matrix.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: The vector in R is always assumed as a column vector. Your mean is a column vector and not a row vector eg run `NCOL(mean)` it will give you 1 while `NROW(mean)` will give you the length=5. Now when you transpose a vector it becomes a row matrix. And thats why you get a 5×5 matrix.in math, For a dot product, always the first one is transposed.always. Not the second one. Hence its x^Tx. Thus in in R its `t(x)%*%x`. Note that x is a vector and not a matrix. Ie `x<-c(unlist(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

In **linear algebra** there is of course the concept of "row vector" and "column vector". When you multiply a row vector by a  column vector you get a  single number (the dot product). When you multiply a column vector by a row vector you get an n X n matrix.

But the `vector` data type in R does not behave that way. In R a vector is a vector, there is no "row" or "column" to it (think of it like an ordered collection). There is, however, a `matrix` data type in R, and of course you can have a matrix with one row, or a matrix with one column. These behave like what you are calling row/column vectors.

The `unlist(...)` function operates on an R `list`. If you pass something that isn't a  list, it just returns the original object. So for instance if you provide an n X k matrix you get back an n X k matrix:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nc=3)
unlist(m)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    4    7
## [2,]    2    5    8
## [3,]    3    6    9
```

The transpose function, `t(...)` returns a matrix, but makes certain assumptions. If you pass an R vector it returns a matrix with one row, in essence converting the vector to a matrix with one column, and transposing that.

```
v <- 1:5    # R vector
t(v)        # returns R matrix with one row
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Finally, the matrix multiplication operator, `%*%` also makes assumptions.

```
x <- 1:5   # R vector
y <- 6:10  # R vector
x %*% y    # converts x to 1-row matrix, y to 1-column matrix
##      [,1]
## [1,]  130

z <- matrix(1:5, nr=1)  # R matrix with one row
z %*% y                 # converts y to 1-column matrix
##      [,1]
## [1,]  130

y %*% z                 # converts y to 1-column martix
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    6   12   18   24   30
## [2,]    7   14   21   28   35
## [3,]    8   16   24   32   40
## [4,]    9   18   27   36   45
## [5,]   10   20   30   40   50
```

The moral of the story is to avoid using (R) vectors and matrices together, the results are completely deterministic, but may not be what you expect. For instance if you have two vectors, `a` and `b` and want the dot product, I'd use `sum(a*b)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed and educational answer! I learned a lot from your comment and was not aware of this difference before. Will definitely go through my code now and improve it.